# Problema al recibir la variable $_GET['q']

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

, tengo estos dos archivos : 1) es script4.js y el 2) es eliminardomiclio.php

script4.js

```
function eliminarRegis(tag,id){
var row=tag.parentNode.parentNode;
var rowclass=row.className;
var calle=document.getElementsByClassName(rowclass)[0].innerHTML;
var numero=document.getElementsByClassName(rowclass)[1].innerHTML;
var datos=new Array();
datos[0]=calle;
datos[1]=numero;
datos[2]=id;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementsById('domregis').innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","eliminardomicilio.php?q="+datos,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

}

eliminardomicilio.php

```
    <?php

    require("conectarBD.php");
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $registro=$_GET["q"];
    $datos=explode(",", $registro);
    $dom=$datos[0];
    $num=$datos[1];
    $idcli=$datos[2];
    $conn=conectarBD();
    $sql="DELETE FROM domicilio WHERE calle='$dom'";
    $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->set_charset('UTF-8');
    $sql="SELECT domicilio.calle AS calle ,domicilio.numero AS numero FROM 
    domicilio WHERE idcliente='$idcli'";
    $domicilios=consultaSQL($conn,$sql);
    desconectarBD($conn);
    ?>
```

Mi codigo HTML

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require("conectarBD.php");
?>
<div class="content_data">
            <!--Domicilios-->
            <table class="domicilios">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Domicilio</th>
                    <th>Numero</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="domregis">
                <?php
                 $idcli=$_SESSION['userlog'];
                 $conn=conectarBD();
                 $conn->set_charset('utf8');
                 $sql="SELECT calle , numero FROM domicilio WHERE idcliente='$idcli'";
                 $datos=consultaSQL($conn,$sql);
                 desconectarBD($conn);
                 if($datos==NULL){
                    unset($datos);
                 }else{
                    $i=0;

                 while($i<count($datos)){
                    $domString[$i]=$datos[$i]['calle'];
                    $i++;
                 }
                 $i=0;
                 while($i<count($datos)){
                    $numString[$i]=$datos[$i]['numero'];
                    $i++;
                 }
                 $i=0;
                 while($i<count($datos)){
                    $d=$domString[$i];
                    $n=$numString[$i];
                    echo "<tr class=\"$i\"><td>$d</td><td>$n</td><td><button class=\"e_n_button\" onclick=\"eliminarRegis(this,'$idcli')\">Eliminar</button></td></tr>";
                    $i++;
                 }
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

El problema que estoy tenienedo es que en el archivo eliminardomicilio.php no me reconoce el parametro "q" que se lo paso en el URL ,de xmlhttp.open() ,  en la funcion script4.js.
Me fije en Internet y se pasa de esa manera tal como esta escrita.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: No puedes pasar un array u objeto por get, debes pasar variables sueltas o serializado.

Comment: Probe pasando un unico dato del arreglo (pasado a string) pero me sigue dando el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de enviar el ajax convierte el array en string usando `toString()`

```
datos = datos.toString();
xmlhttp.open("GET","eliminardomicilio.php?q="+datos,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

y con eso el explode en el php funcionara bien.

Saludos.

Comment: Lo probe pero sigue tirandome el mismo erro.

Answer (score 0):

**debes enviarlos atraves de send:**

```
var datos = new FormData({"calle": calle ,"numero":numero,"id":id});
// datos.psuh("files",files) en caso de querer enviar imagenes
xmlhttp.open("GET","eliminardomicilio.php);
xhr.send(datos);
```

**y en php recibes con:**

```
$dom=$_GET["calle"];
$num=$_GET["numero"];
$idcli=$_GET["id"];
```

Comment: Lo probe , pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error que dice "Undefined Index" para los campos de "calle" "numero" "id".

Comment: puedes publicar tu html no entiendo porque recojes los datos con innerHTML!

Comment: Ya lo publique.